# Why won't the planets rotate in Nbody.java?

Tags: java, physics

I am trying to tackle the Nbody example in my java class (this is my first semester in java).

The Details of the program are as follows:

Write a program Nbody.java that reads in the universe from standard input using Scanner, simulates its dynamics using the leapfrog scheme described above, and animates it using our StdDraw. Maintain several arrays to store the data. To make the computer simulation, write an infinite loop that repeatedly updates the position and velocity of the particles. When plotting, consider using StdDraw.setXscale(-R, +R) and StdDraw.setYscale(-R, +R) to scale the physics coordinates to the screen coordinates.

I've written the following code which compiles & loads the background image, the song, & the planets with correct placement. However, I cannot get the plantes to rotate as they should.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Nbody {

// method dist calculates distance between two points
// it accepts four double values (x1, y1, x2, y2)
// it returns a double value
private static double dist(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)

{

     double r;
     r = Math.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2));
     return r;
} 


public static void main(String[] args) {

    final double G = 6.67e-11; // constant value G

    final double deltaT = 25000.0; // constant value delta T, which determines animation interval

    // ax and ay are accerlations on x axis and y axis
    double ax;
    double ay;


    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in); // define a keyboard object: scan

    int bodyNum = scan.nextInt(); // read in the first integer, which specify how many particles
    double radius = scan.nextDouble(); // read in radius of universe


    // define arrays to save x values and y values of each particle
    double[] x = new double[bodyNum];
    double[] y = new double[bodyNum];

    // define arrays to save velocity of each particle
    double[] vx = new double[bodyNum];
    double[] vy = new double[bodyNum];

    double[] m = new double[bodyNum];  // array stores mass of each particle
    String[] name = new String[bodyNum]; // array stores file name of each particles
    double[] Fx = new double[bodyNum]; // force on X axis
    double[] Fy = new double[bodyNum]; // force on Y axis

    StdDraw.setXscale(-radius, radius); // Set the X scale
    StdDraw.setYscale(-radius, radius); // Set the Y scale
    StdDraw.picture(0, 0, "starfield.jpg"); // Display background pic centered at (0,0)

    // read in inital location values and velocity values for each particle

    for (int i = 0; i < bodyNum; i++)

    {
       x[i] = scan.nextDouble();
       y[i] = scan.nextDouble();
       vx[i] = scan.nextDouble();
       vy[i] = scan.nextDouble();
       m[i] = scan.nextDouble();
       name[i] = scan.next();
       StdDraw.picture(x[i], y[i], name[i]); // display particle pic on screen
    }

    // This following line play background music, uncomment it in lab
    // If you work from a remote location via VNC, comment it
    StdAudio.play("2001.mid");

    // main animation loop
    while(true){

        // array Fx and Fy store net force acting on each body
        // initialize these two arrays to zeros

        for (int n = 0; n<bodyNum; n++)

        {
           Fx[n] = 0.0;
           Fy[n] = 0.0;
        }

         //  for loop to process all bodies
         for(int body = 0; body<bodyNum; body++)

            {

            // calculate the gravitational attraction between current body
            // and all other bodies

            Fx[body] = (m[body] * m[body+1])  / (x[body+1] -x[body])*G;

            Fy[body] = (m[body] * m[body+1]) / (y[body+1] -y[body])*G;

                for (int j = 0; j < bodyNum; j++)

                {

                 // calculate only when two bodies are different
                 // Please fill out the following if statement body                 

                 if(body != j)

                 {

                 Fx[j] = (m[j] * m[j+1]) / (y[j+1] -y[j])*G;
                 Fy[j] = (m[j] * m[j+1]) / (y[j+1] -y[j])*G;


                 }


                }
            }

         // update vleocity value and location value for each particle
         // please fill out the for loop
         for (int j = 0; j < bodyNum; j++)

            {

             // calculate accleration rate
             ax = Fx[j] / m[j];
             ay = Fy[j] / m[j];

             // update vleocity value 

            vx[j] = vx[j] + deltaT * ax;
            vy[j] = vy[j] + deltaT * ay;

            // update location value

            x[j] = x[j] + deltaT * vx[j];
            y[j] = y[j] + deltaT * vy[j];


            } 

         // redraw background
         StdDraw.setXscale(-radius, radius);
         StdDraw.setYscale(-radius, radius);
         StdDraw.picture(0, 0, "starfield.jpg");

         for (int i = 0; i < bodyNum; i++){
             // display the particle           
             StdDraw.picture(x[i], y[i], name[i]);
         }

         // display and pause for 30ms      
         StdDraw.show(30);        
    }
}
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: What exactly isn't working right? Is the calculation wrong, or the display? If the latter, have you tried printing out the results of each iteration so you can see if the positions/velocities are being updated, and are plausible? Remember that StdDraw isn't part of standard Java, so we can't easily try your program out...

Comment: I believe it's the calculations that are wrong. Looking back, I have the same equation written for calculating the gravitational attraction between the current body & all other bodies as well as only when two bodies are different..

Comment: I'm also receiving a run time error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
 at Nbody.main(Nbody.java:107)

Comment: can you check after this line " y[j] = y[j] + deltaT * vy[j];"  are x[j] and y[j] values changing?

Comment: I fixed the run time error, in my two for loops where I defined the variable as 1 & then subtracted the variable by 1, It was causing the array to run out of bounds....Now the planets appear, and then all but one display in the top right corner, and that planet slowly rotates until out of site.

Comment: I also added "System.out.println(x[0] + "," + y[0] + "," + x[1] + "," + y[1]);" right outside the forloop you inquired about & receive a very long output of: Infinity,Infinity,2.279E11,0.0
Infinity,Infinity,Infinity,Infinity
Infinity,Infinity,Infinity,Infinity
Infinity,Infinity,Infinity,Infinity
Infinity,Infinity,Infinity,Infinity
NaN,NaN,Infinity,Infinity
NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
NaN,NaN,NaN,NaN
.........

Comment: I think no change, therefore your planet every time same location. Did you see Ted Hopp's solution.

Comment: yes his solution makes sense, I like his thought process behind it, but I'm having trouble compiling his code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your force calculations seem quite a bit off to me. I'd do it like this:

```
Arrays.fill(Fx, 0.0);
Arrays.fill(Fy, 0.0);
for (int body = 0; body < bodyNum - 1; body++) {
    for (int body2 = body + 1; body2 < bodyNum; body2++) {
        double dx = x[body2] - x[body];
        double dy = y[body2] - y[body];
        double d2 = dx * dx + dy * dy;
        double d = Math.sqrt(d2);
        double f = G * m[body] * m[body2] / d2;
        double fx = f * dx / d;
        double fy = f * dy / d;
        Fx[body] += fx;
        Fy[body] += fy;
        Fx[body2] -= fx;
        Fy[body2] -= fy;
    }
}
// then update positions and velocities based on Fx and Fy arrays
```

This computes the x and y components of the force acting on `body` due to `body2` and then adds that to the x and y force components for `body` and subtracts them from `body2`. By indexing from `body + 1`, we can account for equal-and-opposite forces on two bodies in the same inner loop pass, reducing the number of calculations by half.

For updating positions, you are using the velocity at the end of the time delta, as if the bodies were moving for the entire delta at the velocity at the end of the delta. It might be more accurate to do some sort of interpolation, but that should be a second order effect.

Comment: the new doubles you defined are generating errors when i try to compile "due to incompatible types" :/

Comment: change to: double fx = f * dx / d; double fy = f * dy / d;

Comment: Hmmm, now I'm back to the issue of the planets not updating & receiving an array out of bounds error at line 95 (double dx = x[body2] - x[body])

Comment: for updating velocities & positions we're supposed to be using the "leapfrog method" thats why I am using deltaT as I am

Comment: could you solve "bounds error" problem?

Comment: I dont have any idea about "leapfrog method" and calculations. I can advice only java coding :) Did you check the x[j] and y[j] values? I think these values must be change contionusly..

Comment: @Ryan - Sorry about the missing type declarations for `fx` and `fy`; I updated the code for the next person. As far as array out of bounds: I had a typo in the inner loop (for `body2`); the wrong variable was being incremented. That's also now fixed. Sorry that I didn't notice your requirement to use leapfrogging. Just ignore my last paragraph.

Comment: @TedHopp This has the planets rotating! I'm just having trouble conceptualizing what your method is actually doing. Also, it wouldn't compile with your two lines "Arrays.fill.....". I'm not familiar with that statement so I just removed it for now.

Comment: @Ryan - You probably just needed to import `java.util.Arrays`. But if you fill the arrays with a loop, that works just as well. The concept is, first, to compute the magnitude (f) of the force between body and body2. Then compute the components of the force vector acting on body (that's fx and fy). Finally, add those to the total force vector acting on body (Fx[body] and Fy[body]) and subtract them from the total force vector acting on body2 (Fx[body2] and Fy[body2]). I'm careful to index body2 starting at body1+1 (not at 0) so as to not double-count any of the forces.

Comment: @TedHopp Gotcha, sorry physics isn't my strong point! I'm just trying to simplify the math on the inside since we've already defined: 
private static double dist(double x1, double y1, double x2, double y2)

{

     double r;
     r = Math.sqrt((x1-x2)*(x1-x2) + (y1-y2)*(y1-y2));
     return r;
} 
at the top

Comment: @Ryan - Yeah, I saw that. The problem with using that is that you also need the squared distance and it seems silly to compute the squared distance, take the square root, and then square it again (which is what you'd have to do to use `dist`). Also, you need dx and dy separately to compute the force vector components. At the end of the day, that means that using `dist` isn't any simplification at all.